# Understanding F-bound polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala, f-bounded-polymorphism

I'm trying to understand how it works. Here is what I tried:

```
abstract class TestBase { self =>
  type T >: self.type <: TestBase
}

class Test1 extends TestBase {
  type T = Test1
}

class Test2 extends Test1{
  override type T = Test1 // daaaaamn
}
```

The problem is if the inheritance hierarchy has length more than 2. In case of Test2 it was definitely not what I wanted. Is there a way to prevent something like that happened at compile time?

Comment: What are you trying to do (as in: what compile-time invariants are you trying to uphold)? My understanding of the F-bound trick is to try to prevent things like `Test2`.

Comment: @Alec Yes, but this still compiles..

Comment: OK - I definitely misunderstood your point. I'm still not sure I understand fully your question though. Are you trying to prevent inheritance chains of length more than 2? Or just make it so that in those cases `T` cannot be different from the class type itself?

Comment: @Alec Yes, the goal is to prevent more than 2 inheritance or make `Test2` has only `type T = Test2`

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. I'm no expert in this, but I think that F-bounded polymorphism is generally regarded as a bit of a hack. It certainly can be abused (which is why uses are usually `sealed`) in ways such as the one you have put forth.

Answer (score 2):

As @Alec points out the short answer is unfortunately it appears you can't do this; however, most instances where you want to constrain types in a manner afforded by F-bounded types can be replaced with typeclasses. [Rob Norris has a good discussion](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) of F-bounded types vs typeclasses and touches briefly on the problem you're experiencing.